# Criterion of Lebesgue integrability of finite measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu(A)<\infty$, and the function $f(x)$ is measurable and finite on $A$. Suppose that $E_k(f)=\{x\in A: k\leq |f(x)|<k+1\}$ for $k\geq 0$. Prove that $f(x)\in L(A)$ iff $$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}k\mu(E_k(f))<\infty.$$

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $f(x)\in L(A)$ then $|f(x)|\in L(A)$. Since $f(x)$ is finite on $A$ then $A=\sqcup_{k=0}^{\infty} E_k(f)$. For each $n\geq 0$ consider the function $F_n(x)=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}|f(x)|\chi_{E_k}(x)$ then $\{F_n(x)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a family of measurable functions on $A$ such that $F_n(x)\to |f(x)|$ for each $x\in A$ and $|F_n(x)|\leq |f(x)|$ for all $n\geq 1$. Then by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem it follows that $$\int \limits_{A}|f(x)|d\mu=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{A}F_n(x)d\mu=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \int \limits_{A}|f(x)|\chi_{E_k}(x)d\mu\geq $$ $$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \int \limits_{A}k\chi_{E_k}(x)d\mu=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} k\mu(E_k)<\infty.$$

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose that $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} k\mu(E_k)<\infty$. We see that functions $\{F_n(x)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are nonnegative, non-decreasing measurable functions on $A$ such that $F_n(x)\to |f(x)|$ for each $x\in A$. Then by monotone convergence theorem $$\int\limits_{A}|f(x)|d\mu=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{A}F_n(x)d\mu=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{A}|f(x)|\chi_{E_k}(x)d\mu<\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{A}(k+1)\chi_{E_k}(x)d\mu=$$$$=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)\mu(E_k)<\infty$$ because $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}k\mu(E_k)<\infty$.

I checked my solution and I have never used the fact that $\mu(A)<\infty$. What's wrong with solution?

Answer (score 2):

The last statement is not correct. If $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\mu(E_k)<\infty$, then it may happen that  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)\mu(E_k)=\infty$. Thus happens when $k=0$ and $\mu(E_0)=\infty$. The usual convention in measure theory tells you that $0\cdot\infty=0$ so the first sum is finite, but not the second one.

A related counterexample would be a constant function $f=1/2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Are you sure? Let $a_k\geq 0$ and since $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}ka_k<\infty$ then $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k<\infty$ because $a_k\leq ka_k$.

Comment: @ZFR $a_k\leq ka_k$ is false $k=0$ unless $a_0=0$.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah you're right. Since $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty}ka_k=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}ka_k<\infty$ then it follows that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(k+1)a_k<\infty$ but we are considering the series which has also one additional term $a_0$. If $a_0=\infty$ then my claim is indeed wrong. But if $\mu(A)<\infty$ then $a_0<\infty$ because $E_0(f)\subset A$. Right?